# New to CSS/HTML - dropdown options are offset?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, web

I'm a total newbie to CSS and HTML but I'm slowly constructing a website for uni. One thing that's bugging me: I can't figure out how to align the dropdown options. They're slightly off-centre, as shown in the screenshot 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6OD1.png). I'll paste the actual CSS below too (the preview doesn't work so don't bother with that. The code actually does work when run in Brackets, however):

```css
  ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      padding-left: 0px;
}
  ul li {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      border:1px solid #ed85c4; 
      text-align:center; 
}
  li ul {
      display: none;
}
  ul li a {
      display: block;
      background: #ffeff8;
      padding: 4px 20px 2px 25px;
      text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;
      color: #ed85c4;
      font-family: Luna;
      font-size: 14px;
}
  ul li a:hover {
      background: #f1dae8;
}
  li:hover ul {
      display: block; 
      position: absolute;
}
  li:hover li {
      float: none;
}
  li:hover a {
      background: #ffeff8;
      color: #ed85c4
}
  li:hover li a:hover {
    background: #f1dae8;
      color: #d771ae
}
  li:hover li {
      color:#d771ae
}
  #drop-nav li ul li {
      border-top: 0px;
}
  ul {
      display:table;
      margin:auto;} 

}
```

And here's the html (ignore that the links are currently empty):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head><meta charset="UF-8">
    <title>Happea Organic Restaurant</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type ="text/css">
</head>
<body>
      <center><img src="images/eskimoo.png" width="600"></center>
    
   <ul id="drop-nav">
   <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">history</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">values</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">the truck</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">produce info.</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">menus</a>
  <li><a href="#">events</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">upcoming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">past</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">booking/hiring</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
         <li><a href="#">find us</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">truck tracker</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">offices</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">message us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">newsletter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
    <li><a href="#">extras</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">competitions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">mascot</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
        </ul>
    
    <br><br>
    <c><img src="images/pad.png" width=1000></c>
 </body>


    <br><br><br>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the part of Html code which is concerned? It'd help.

Comment: Also, instead of using `block`, try using `inline-block` in your `display` properties (for `ul li a`, for instance).

Comment: Sure thing, I'll add the html into the post now. And I've just tried that, unfortunately everything's shifted further! (http://imgur.com/w0aqth5)

Comment: Technically, you should be able to edit your post to add Html code to it. In any case, the change you made vertically aligned your menu items, so it's a good start. You can now set a `min-width` so that every item will have the same `width`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site, it's in the post now! I'll try adding a min-width. Thanks for your help so far, I appreciate it.

Comment: Afterwards, if it isn't still looking the way you want it, try adding `position: absolute;` to `li ul a`, i think that should do it. And you're welcome!